# Colored Noise Generation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i would like to ask  help about how to generate  different noises in signal processing,according to this definition

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise

where for white noise  alpha=0;,and for different noises we have different values of alpha,i prefer to have  code in matlab,so please help me to write  this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18269-simulation-of-color-noise). It is very straigthforward:

```
function [W,t]= colornoise(a,b,T,N)
 randn('state',100);      %fixing the state of generator
 dt=T/N;
 dW=sqrt(dt)*randn(1,N);

 R=4;                      %fixed for this computation
 L=N/R;
 Xem=zeros(1,L);
 Xzero=0;
 Xtemp=Xzero;
 Dt=R*dt;

 for j=1:L
    Winc=sum(dW(R*(j-1)+1:R*j));
    Xtemp=Xtemp+a*Dt*Xtemp+b*Winc;
    Xem(j)=Xtemp;
 end

 W=[Xzero,Xem];
 t=[0:Dt:T]
```

where `a`,`b` (intensity of white noise) and `T` (the upper limit to time vector), `N` (the no. of samples which essentially defines the step size

Answer (score 0):

Generate a pink noise signal 2048 samples in length.

```
hcn = dsp.ColoredNoise('InverseFrequencyPower',1,'SamplesPerFrame',2048);
x = step(hcn);
plot(x);
```